# How to resolve : "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am launching a spring boot application with this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class ProduitImmobilierController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProduitImmobilierController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProduitImmobilierService produitImmobilierService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all/{pageSize}/{page}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> findAll(@PathVariable("pageSize") int pageSize, @PathVariable("page") int page){
        logger.info("CONTROLLER PRODUITIMMOBILIERSERVICE CA PASSE");
        return produitImmobilierService.findAll(pageSize, page);
    }
```

I check that the application is listening on port 8080
I try to access this controller with this URL on firefox

http://localhost:8080/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1

And I get this error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Nov 13 20:48:53 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Here is the project tree

[image]

How can I resolve it?

I add the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoImmobilierBack</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoImmobilierBack</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.hql</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hql-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
<!--            <version>1.4.194</version> -->
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

When I hit the application with the url : http://localhost:8080/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1

```
2019-11-14 12:20:58.770  INFO 2998 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-14 12:20:58.770  INFO 2998 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-14 12:20:58.787  INFO 2998 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
```

Comment: `consumes` why is this required for method = RequestMethod.GET?

Comment: yes of course, i removed it, and there is still the same error

Comment: Can you log the result of produitImmobilierService.findAll(pageSize, page)?

Comment: I can assure there is no problem with produitImmobilierService.findAll(pageSize, page). It used to work, but not any more, without changing this part. What is your idea ?

Comment: The first time I hit the request, I could see the following log. Visibilly, it hit tomcat on the port 8080 (see the following)

Comment: 2019-11-14 07:35:37.689  INFO 801 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-14 07:35:37.689  INFO 801 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-11-14 07:35:37.707  INFO 801 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 18 ms

Comment: But it doesn't go into the method and cannot find the mapped url

Comment: I added above the pom.xml

Comment: Can you move the ResponseBody annotation outside of the method so it looks like '@ResponseBody public List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> findAll(...)  '

Comment: Can you check if the startup logs showing mapping of this URI. Error says resource not found, that means URI you are tying to access is not available. May be not getting scanned by SpringBootApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ProduitImmobilierController {
        ...
        ...
        ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the class containing main method, adding @ComponentScan as follows

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service","com.example.demoImmobilierBack", "com.example.demoImmobilierBack.controller", "com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository"})
public class DemoImmobilierBackApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoImmobilierBackApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and when I hit the url :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1
```

And I received the following error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Nov 14 21:11:26 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

I read this about error 406

```
The 406 Not Acceptable is an HTTP response status code indicating that the client has requested a response using Accept- headers that the server is unable to fulfill. This is typically a result of the user agent (i.e. browser) specifying an acceptable character set (via Accept-Charset), language (via Accept-Language), and so forth that should be responded with, and the server being unable to provide such a response.
```

I work on firefox and tried to change the user agent with User-Agent Switcher, in order to get a proper response, that is, a json response, without succes

I had another issue. When I tried to add another controller with another service in my application, that is

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.UserDTOWithMesssage;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/user"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody UserDTOWithMesssage login(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
        UserDTOWithMesssage userDTOWithMesssage = new UserDTOWithMesssage();
        String message = userService.checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(userDTO);
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            userDTO = userService.findByEmailAndPassword(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
            userDTO.setPassword("");
        } else {
            userDTOWithMesssage.setMessage(message);
        }
        return userDTOWithMesssage;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody UserDTOWithMesssage save(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
        UserDTOWithMesssage userDTOWithMesssage = new UserDTOWithMesssage();
        String message = userService.checkEmailAndPasswordAndPasswordConfirm(userDTO);
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            UserDTO userDTOSaved = userService.save(userDTO);
            userDTOWithMesssage.setUserDTO(userDTOSaved);
            userDTOWithMesssage.setMessage(message);
        } else {
            userDTOWithMesssage.setUserDTO(userDTO);
            userDTOWithMesssage.setMessage("");         
        }
        return userDTOWithMesssage;
    }
}
```

When I start the application, I obtain the following error, as if the UserService could not be scanned

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userService in com.example.demoImmobilierBack.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service.UserService' in your configuration.
```

Here is the tree hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Have you tried annotating `DemoImmobilierBackApplication` with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack")` ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, effectively, when I put the following, it works

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack")

But I have still the issue with UserService. Here is the interface

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User;

public interface UserService {

    UserDTO findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);

    UserDTO save(UserDTO userDTO);

    String checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(UserDTO userDTO);

    UserDTO convertUserToUserDTO(User user);

    User convertUserDTOToUser(UserDTO userDTO);

    String checkEmailAndPasswordAndPasswordConfirm(UserDTO userDTO);
}
```

Here is the implementation

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.ProduitImmobilierDTO;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.dto.UserDTO;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.ProduitImmobilier;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.ProduitImmobilierRepository;
import com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.UserRepository;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = 
            Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static final Pattern VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = 
            Pattern.compile("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}");

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProduitImmobilierService produitImmobilierService;

    public UserDTO findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return convertUserToUserDTO(user);
    }

    public UserDTO save(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User user = userRepository.save(convertUserDTOToUser(userDTO));
        return convertUserToUserDTO(user);
    }

    public String checkEmailAndPasswordAndPasswordConfirm(UserDTO userDTO) {
        Matcher matcher = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX .matcher(userDTO.getEmail());
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return "L'email que vous avez fourni: " + userDTO.getEmail() + " n'est pas valide";
        }
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        if (user != null) {
            return "L'utilisateur avec l'email suivant " + userDTO.getEmail() + " existe déjà";
        }
        matcher = VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX .matcher(userDTO.getPassword());
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return "Le mot de passe que vous avez fourni: " + userDTO.getPassword() + " n'est pas valide. Il doit contenir au moins 8 caractères, un caractère minuscule, un caractère majuscule, un chiffre et un caractère spécial.";
        }
        if (!userDTO.getPassword().equals(userDTO.getPasswordConfirm())) {
            return "Le mot de passe que vous avez fourni: " + userDTO.getPassword() + " ne correspond pas à la confirmation du mot de passe  " + userDTO.getPasswordConfirm();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String checkIfUserExistsAndGoodCredential(UserDTO userDTO) {
        Matcher matcher = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX .matcher(userDTO.getEmail());
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return "L'email que vous avez fourni: " + userDTO.getEmail() + " n'est pas valide";
        }
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        if (user == null) {
            return "L'utilisateur avec l'email suivant " + userDTO.getEmail() + " n'existe pas";
        }
        matcher = VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX .matcher(userDTO.getPassword());
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return "Le mot de passe que vous avez fourni: " + userDTO.getPassword() + " n'est pas valide. Il doit contenir au moins 8 caractères, un caractère minuscule, un caractère majuscule, un chiffre et un caractère spécial.";
        }
        user = userRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
        if (user == null) {
            return "L'utilisateur avec l'email suivant " + userDTO.getEmail() + " et le mot de passe suivant " + userDTO.getPassword() + "n'existe pas";
        }   
        return "";
    }

    public UserDTO convertUserToUserDTO(User user) {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setId(user.getId());
        userDTO.setGender(user.getGender());
        userDTO.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        userDTO.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userDTO.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userDTO.setMobileTelephone(user.getFixedTelephone());
        userDTO.setFixedTelephone(user.getFixedTelephone());
        userDTO.setAdress(user.getAdress());
        userDTO.setPostalCode(user.getPostalCode());
        userDTO.setTown(user.getTown());
        userDTO.setProfession(user.getProfession());
        userDTO.setProfile(user.getProfile());
        userDTO.setMaritalSituation(user.getMaritalSituation());
        userDTO.setChildrenNumber(user.getChildrenNumber());
        userDTO.setDependant(user.getDependant());
        userDTO.setOwnedOrRentedAccommodation(user.getOwnedOrRentedAccommodation());
        userDTO.setMonthlyNetSalary(user.getMonthlyNetSalary());
        userDTO.setRentAmount(user.getRentAmount());
        userDTO.setIsBankLoan(user.getIsBankLoan());
        userDTO.setCapitalContribution(user.getCapitalContribution());
        userDTO.setCreditAmount(user.getCreditAmount());
        userDTO.setMonthlyPayment(user.getMonthlyPayment());
        userDTO.setCreditTerminationDate(user.getCreditTerminationDate());
        userDTO.setSIRETNumber(user.getSIRETNumber());

        Set<ProduitImmobilier> setProduitImmobiliers = user.getRealEstateProperty();
        List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> setProduitImmobilierDTOs = new ArrayList<>();

        setProduitImmobiliers.forEach(p ->{ ProduitImmobilierDTO pDTO = produitImmobilierService.convertProduitImmobilierToProduitImmobilierDTO(p, setProduitImmobiliers.size()); setProduitImmobilierDTOs.add(pDTO);});

        Comparator<ProduitImmobilierDTO> compareByIdDesc = new Comparator<ProduitImmobilierDTO>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ProduitImmobilierDTO o1, ProduitImmobilierDTO o2) {
                return o2.getId().compareTo(o1.getId());
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(setProduitImmobilierDTOs, compareByIdDesc);
        userDTO.setRealEstateProperty(setProduitImmobilierDTOs);
        return userDTO;
    }

    public User convertUserDTOToUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(userDTO.getId());
        user.setGender(userDTO.getGender());
        user.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(userDTO.getPassword());
        user.setMobileTelephone(userDTO.getFixedTelephone());
        user.setFixedTelephone(userDTO.getFixedTelephone());
        user.setAdress(userDTO.getAdress());
        user.setPostalCode(userDTO.getPostalCode());
        user.setTown(userDTO.getTown());
        user.setProfession(userDTO.getProfession());
        user.setProfile(userDTO.getProfile());
        user.setMaritalSituation(userDTO.getMaritalSituation());
        user.setChildrenNumber(userDTO.getChildrenNumber());
        user.setDependant(userDTO.getDependant());
        user.setOwnedOrRentedAccommodation(userDTO.getOwnedOrRentedAccommodation());
        user.setMonthlyNetSalary(userDTO.getMonthlyNetSalary());
        user.setRentAmount(userDTO.getRentAmount());
        user.setIsBankLoan((userDTO.getIsBankLoan().equals(new Byte((byte) 0))) ? false : userDTO.getIsBankLoan().equals(new Byte((byte) 1)) ? true : null  );
        user.setCapitalContribution(userDTO.getCapitalContribution());
        user.setCreditAmount(userDTO.getCreditAmount());
        user.setMonthlyPayment(userDTO.getMonthlyPayment());
        user.setCreditTerminationDate(new Date(userDTO.getCreditTerminationDate()));
        user.setSIRETNumber(userDTO.getSIRETNumber());
        return user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I just forgot to put @Service annotation for UserServiceImpl. Thank you for your replies